# Requesting single location update, AVD crashes

Tags: android, geolocation, location, android-sdk-2.3

I'm trying to request a single location update using the new LocationManager.requestSingleUpdate() method, but once the device gets an update from the GPS the OS crashes and seems to try to reboot. At least I get the usual Android boot screen, but it never finishes booting.

I've tried running the code on a 2.3, 2.3.1, 2.3.3 and 2.2 AVD, with the same result on all.

***** **Update** *****

I tried an old location based app that I have made, and that is running just fine  on a few hundred units, and this also crashes the AVD when sending it a location update. I guess this is turning out be more a case of understanding what is going wrong with location updates to the AVD than spotting an error in my code..?

Below follows the code I thought was at fault, in case it might be relevant:

***** **End update** *****

```
public class LocationHelper {

    public static void getLocation(Context context) {

        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                Log.v("LocationListener", "onStatusChanged");
            }    

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                Log.v("LocationListener", "onProviderEnabled");                
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Log.v("LocationListener", "onProviderDisabled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Log.v("LocationListener", "onLocationChanged");
            }
        };

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Service.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        Log.v("Provider", provider);

        // FIXME: Something crashes the emulator when a GPS fix is sent through DDMS
        locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(provider, locationListener, Looper.myLooper());
    }
}
```

I might also mention that the `provider` variable gets set to "gps", according to the logs. None of the log statements in the LocationListener are triggered.

Below is the output from logcat. The first line shows that my getLocation() function was called. I then submit a gps fix through DDMS, and the phone proceeds to reboot. I cut the log a little short, since I was going over the 30k chars boundary, but I guess the first lines are the most relevant.

```
V/Provider(  430): gps

I/DEBUG   (   31): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***

I/DEBUG   (   31): Build fingerprint: 'generic/google_sdk/generic:2.3/GRH55/79397:eng/test-keys'

I/DEBUG   (   31): pid: 68, tid: 163  >>> system_server <<<

I/DEBUG   (   31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000

I/DEBUG   (   31):  r0 00000000  r1 40685948  r2 4128fcbc  r3 459e1c74

I/DEBUG   (   31):  r4 0000012d  r5 00000000  r6 40685948  r7 4128fcbc

I/DEBUG   (   31):  r8 84301321  r9 84302240  10 00100000  fp 00000001

I/DEBUG   (   31):  ip 82f0e7d4  sp 459e1c60  lr 82f0ab37  pc 82f07d0e  cpsr 00000030

I/DEBUG   (   31):          #00  pc 00007d0e  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so

I/DEBUG   (   31):          #01  pc 0000ab32  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so

I/DEBUG   (   31):          #02  pc 000012ca  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so

I/DEBUG   (   31):          #03  pc 000014ae  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so

I/DEBUG   (   31):          #04  pc 00011a7c  /system/lib/libc.so

I/DEBUG   (   31):          #05  pc 00011640  /system/lib/libc.so

I/DEBUG   (   31): 

I/DEBUG   (   31): code around pc:

I/DEBUG   (   31): 82f07cec ab04b082 9301cb04 6f646804 b00247a0 

I/DEBUG   (   31): 82f07cfc bc08bc10 4718b002 b510b40c ab04b082 

I/DEBUG   (   31): 82f07d0c 6804cb04 34f89301 47a06824 bc10b002 

I/DEBUG   (   31): 82f07d1c b002bc08 46c04718 b510b40c ab04b082 

I/DEBUG   (   31): 82f07d2c 9301cb04 34986804 47a06824 bc10b002 

I/DEBUG   (   31): 

I/DEBUG   (   31): code around lr:

I/DEBUG   (   31): 82f0ab14 91099008 f7fb6aa0 900aeb14 1c3a910b 

I/DEBUG   (   31): 82f0ab24 6b646b23 930c1c28 1c31940d f7fd9b0f 

I/DEBUG   (   31): 82f0ab34 4906f8e7 44791c28 f7ff3150 b011fe1d 

I/DEBUG   (   31): 82f0ab44 46c0bdf0 0000454c 000042c8 00000786 

I/DEBUG   (   31): 82f0ab54 f7fbb510 bd10ec7c 4802b510 f7fb4478 

I/DEBUG   (   31): 

I/DEBUG   (   31): stack:

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c20  ac710cb3  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c24  40b38d0b  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c28  00000009  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c2c  00000000  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c30  0000ab90  [heap]

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c34  81d48bd3  /system/lib/libdvm.so

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c38  0000ab90  [heap]

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c3c  459e1c6c  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c40  00010004  [heap]

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c44  81d3761b  /system/lib/libdvm.so

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c48  00000000  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c4c  afd0dcc4  /system/lib/libc.so

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c50  00000000  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c54  459e1e00  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c58  df002777  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c5c  e3a070ad  

I/DEBUG   (   31): #00 459e1c60  00000001  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c64  8053bf25  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c68  0000012d  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c6c  82f0ab37  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c70  4128fcbc  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c74  00000003  

I/DEBUG   (   31): #01 459e1c78  4284dfce  /system/usr/icu/icudt44l.dat

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c7c  4042b604  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c80  92023d3a  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c84  40490ac3  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c88  00000000  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c8c  00000000  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c90  00000000  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c94  00000000  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c98  00000000  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1c9c  00000000  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1ca0  00000000  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1ca4  00000000  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1ca8  c4571f00  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1cac  0000012d  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1cb0  459e1e56  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1cb4  00000003  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1cb8  0000000a  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1cbc  459e1de8  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1cc0  00000000  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1cc4  459e1e6b  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1cc8  00000001  

I/DEBUG   (   31):     459e1ccc  843012cd  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so

I/StatusBarManagerService(   68): registerStatusBar bar=com.android.internal.statusbar.IStatusBar$Stub$Proxy@40692170

D/VoldCmdListener(   29): share status ums

D/StorageNotification(  278): Startup with UMS connection false (media state mounted)

I/StorageNotification(  278): UMS connection changed to false (media state mounted)

D/dalvikvm(  278): GC_CONCURRENT freed 501K, 55% free 2668K/5831K, external 897K/1038K, paused 9ms+6ms

I/ActivityManager(   68): Process com.android.defcontainer (pid 218) has died.

D/Zygote  (   33): Process 68 terminated by signal (11)

I/Zygote  (   33): Exit zygote because system server (68) has terminated

I/ActivityThread(  415): Removing dead content provider: settings

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'batteryinfo' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'usagestats' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'SurfaceFlinger' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'package' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'sensorservice' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'cpuinfo' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'entropy' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'power' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'account' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'telephony.registry' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'appwidget' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'backup' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'permission' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'activity' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'meminfo' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'diskstats' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'content' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'battery' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'hardware' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'vibrator' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'alarm' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'window' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'device_policy' died

I/ActivityThread(  278): Removing dead content provider: settings

I/ActivityThread(  125): Removing dead content provider: settings

I/ActivityThread(  122): Removing dead content provider: settings

I/ActivityThread(  430): Removing dead content provider: settings

E/installd(   35): eof

E/installd(   35): failed to read size

I/installd(   35): closing connection

D/qemud   (   38): fdhandler_event: disconnect on fd 11

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'statusbar' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'clipboard' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'network_management' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'input_method' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'netstat' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'wifi' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'connectivity' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'throttle' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'accessibility' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'mount' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'notification' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'devicestoragemonitor' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'location' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'search' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'dropbox' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'wallpaper' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'audio' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'uimode' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'isms' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'simphonebook' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'iphonesubinfo' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'phone' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'media.audio_flinger' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'media.audio_policy' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'media.player' died

I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'media.camera' died

I/Netd    (  445): Netd 1.0 starting

D/AndroidRuntime(  446): 

D/AndroidRuntime(  446): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<

D/AndroidRuntime(  446): CheckJNI is ON

I/        (  444): ServiceManager: 0xad50

D/AudioHardwareInterface(  444): setMode(NORMAL)

I/CameraService(  444): CameraService started (pid=444)

I/AudioFlinger(  444): AudioFlinger's thread 0xc650 ready to run

I/SamplingProfilerIntegration(  446): Profiler is disabled.

I/Zygote  (  446): Preloading classes...

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 47K, 78% free 232K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 33ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1K, 73% free 282K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 17ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 22K, 70% free 316K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 19ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 17K, 66% free 353K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 8ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 26K, 63% free 382K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 19ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 20K, 58% free 439K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 20ms

W/MediaProfiles(  446): could not find media config xml file

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 99K, 47% free 545K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 24ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 272K, 28% free 884K/1219K, external 0K/0K, paused 45ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 21K, 24% free 931K/1219K, external 0K/0K, paused 41ms

D/RenderScript_jni(  446): RenderScript JNI library not found!

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 25K, 19% free 998K/1219K, external 0K/0K, paused 51ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 47K, 5% free 1281K/1347K, external 0K/0K, paused 64ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 24K, 3% free 1310K/1347K, external 0K/0K, paused 72ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 28K, 6% free 1336K/1411K, external 0K/0K, paused 63ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 14K, 3% free 1376K/1411K, external 0K/0K, paused 75ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 28K, 5% free 1402K/1475K, external 0K/0K, paused 64ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 28K, 3% free 1439K/1475K, external 0K/0K, paused 78ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 38K, 6% free 1456K/1539K, external 0K/0K, paused 77ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 40K, 5% free 1471K/1539K, external 0K/0K, paused 76ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 55K, 8% free 1485K/1603K, external 0K/0K, paused 75ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2956K, 58% free 2166K/5123K, external 0K/0K, paused 273ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1401K, 55% free 2309K/5123K, external 0K/0K, paused 162ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 141K, 55% free 2355K/5123K, external 0K/0K, paused 146ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 73K, 54% free 2380K/5123K, external 0K/0K, paused 162ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 36K, 54% free 2398K/5123K, external 0K/0K, paused 139ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 30K, 53% free 2421K/5123K, external 0K/0K, paused 140ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 38K, 53% free 2444K/5123K, external 0K/0K, paused 141ms

I/Zygote  (  446): ...preloaded 1830 classes in 23652ms.

E/Zygote  (  446): setreuid() failed. errno: 17

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 18K, 53% free 2442K/5123K, external 0K/0K, paused 153ms

I/Zygote  (  446): Preloading resources...

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 53% free 2444K/5123K, external 0K/0K, paused 141ms

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080093 (res/drawable-mdpi/sym_def_app_icon.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080002 (res/drawable-mdpi/arrow_down_float.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800b4 (res/drawable/btn_check.xml) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800b7 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_label_background.9.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800b8 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800bd (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080004 (res/drawable/btn_default.xml) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080005 (res/drawable/btn_default_small.xml) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080006 (res/drawable/btn_dropdown.xml) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080008 (res/drawable/btn_plus.xml) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080007 (res/drawable/btn_minus.xml) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080009 (res/drawable/btn_radio.xml) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108000a (res/drawable/btn_star.xml) that varies with configuration!!

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 25K, 52% free 2481K/5123K, external 408K/521K, paused 128ms

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080132 (res/drawable/btn_toggle.xml) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080196 (res/drawable-mdpi/ic_emergency.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080012 (res/drawable-mdpi/divider_horizontal_bright.9.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080014 (res/drawable-mdpi/divider_horizontal_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080016 (res/drawable/edit_text.xml) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080170 (res/drawable/expander_group.xml) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080062 (res/drawable/list_selector_background.xml) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108022a (res/drawable-mdpi/menu_background.9.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108022b (res/drawable-mdpi/menu_background_fill_parent_width.9.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108022c (res/drawable/menu_selector.xml) that varies with configuration!!

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 16K, 52% free 2494K/5123K, external 516K/521K, paused 135ms

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108023a (res/drawable-mdpi/panel_background.9.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080242 (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_bottom_bright.9.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080243 (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_bottom_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080244 (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_bottom_medium.9.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080245 (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_center_bright.9.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080246 (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_center_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080249 (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_full_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108024c (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_top_bright.9.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108024d (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_top_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108006d (res/drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal.xml) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080253 (res/drawable/progress_small.xml) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080254 (res/drawable/progress_small_titlebar.xml) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080274 (res/drawable-mdpi/scrollbar_handle_horizontal.9.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080275 (res/drawable-mdpi/scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png) that varies with configuration!!

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 15K, 52% free 2506K/5123K, external 585K/1038K, paused 142ms

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080071 (res/drawable/spinner_dropdown_background.xml) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080304 (res/drawable-mdpi/text_select_handle_left.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080305 (res/drawable-mdpi/text_select_handle_middle.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080306 (res/drawable-mdpi/text_select_handle_right.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080327 (res/drawable-mdpi/title_bar_shadow.9.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801d8 (res/drawable-mdpi/indicator_code_lock_drag_direction_green_up.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801d9 (res/drawable-mdpi/indicator_code_lock_drag_direction_red_up.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801da (res/drawable-mdpi/indicator_code_lock_point_area_default.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801db (res/drawable-mdpi/indicator_code_lock_point_area_green.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  (  446): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801dc (res/drawable-mdpi/indicator_code_lock_point_area_red.png) that varies with configuration!!

I/Zygote  (  446): ...preloaded 51 resources in 2898ms.

I/Zygote  (  446): ...preloaded 15 resources in 64ms.

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 23K, 51% free 2514K/5123K, external 716K/1038K, paused 134ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed 6K, 52% free 2508K/5123K, external 716K/1038K, paused 128ms

D/dalvikvm(  446): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 52% free 2508K/5123K, external 716K/1038K, paused 224ms

I/dalvikvm(  446): System server process 453 has been created

I/Zygote  (  446): Accepting command socket connections

E/BatteryService(  453): usbOnlinePath not found

E/BatteryService(  453): batteryVoltagePath not found

E/BatteryService(  453): batteryTemperaturePath not found

I/sysproc (  453): Entered system_init()

I/sysproc (  453): ServiceManager: 0x8fbe8

I/SurfaceFlinger(  453): SurfaceFlinger is starting

I/SurfaceFlinger(  453): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...

E/SurfaceFlinger(  453): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake

I/gralloc (  453): using (fd=27)

I/gralloc (  453): id           = 

I/gralloc (  453): xres         = 320 px

I/gralloc (  453): yres         = 480 px

I/gralloc (  453): xres_virtual = 320 px

I/gralloc (  453): yres_virtual = 960 px

I/gralloc (  453): bpp          = 16

I/gralloc (  453): r            = 11:5

I/gralloc (  453): g            =  5:6

I/gralloc (  453): b            =  0:5

I/gralloc (  453): width        = 49 mm (165.877548 dpi)

I/gralloc (  453): height       = 74 mm (164.756760 dpi)

I/gralloc (  453): refresh rate = 60.00 Hz

D/libEGL  (  453): egl.cfg not found, using default config

D/libEGL  (  453): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so

I/SurfaceFlinger(  453): EGL informations:

I/SurfaceFlinger(  453): # of configs : 8

I/SurfaceFlinger(  453): vendor    : Android

I/SurfaceFlinger(  453): version   : 1.4 Android META-EGL

I/SurfaceFlinger(  453): extensions: EGL_KHR_image EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_KHR_image_pixmap EGL_ANDROID_image_native_buffer EGL_ANDROID_swap_rectangle 

I/SurfaceFlinger(  453): Client API: OpenGL ES

I/SurfaceFlinger(  453): EGLSurface: 5-6-5-0, config=0x0

I/SurfaceFlinger(  453): OpenGL informations:

I/SurfaceFlinger(  453): vendor    : Android

I/SurfaceFlinger(  453): renderer  : Android PixelFlinger 1.4

I/SurfaceFlinger(  453): version   : OpenGL ES-CM 1.0

I/SurfaceFlinger(  453): extensions: GL_OES_byte_coordinates GL_OES_fixed_point GL_OES_single_precision GL_OES_read_format GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_draw_texture GL_OES_matrix_get GL_OES_query_matrix GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ANDROID_user_clip_plane GL_ANDROID_vertex_buffer_object GL_ANDROID_generate_mipmap 

I/SurfaceFlinger(  453): GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 4096

I/SurfaceFlinger(  453): GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS = 4096

I/SurfaceFlinger(  453): flags = 000c0000

D/SensorService(  453): nuSensorService starting...

E/SensorService(  453): couldn't open device for module sensors (Invalid argument)

I/sysproc (  453): System server: starting Android runtime.

I/sysproc (  453): System server: starting Android services.
```

I'm requesting the following permissions in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Please attached the stacktrace from DDMS. Also  why do you pass `new Criteria()` to `getBestProvider` since you are creating and setting a criteria right before and never use it? Also check if you have set the required permissions in the Manifest

Comment: Sorry, I guess the details were a bit lacking. I fixed the `new Criteria()` error, and rerun my code to make sure it was still failing. I also added the logcat output (if by stacktrace from ddms you mean somthing else, I'm not familiar with it), as well as the `<uses-permissions>` entries in my manifest.

Comment: Hum, have you tried some Android API demos or other small and basic demo out there (using Location) if it runs fine on your AVD?

Comment: Sorry, it seems I dropped the ball on this one. I could not find an API demo, but now that I try another location based app I have written, and that is running fine on a few hundred phones, it indeed crashes the AVD too. I have also upgraded the SDK platform to version 2.3.3, but it gives the same result. Pretty slow thing to try to debug, as I have to restart the AVD on every attempt. :) Updated the question and title to reflect the new info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [a bug in the 2.3 emulator](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13015) that causes this problem. There is no fix at this time.