# Android 2.3 emulator crashes when updating location

Tags: android, crash, location, emulation

I am using Eclipse to write and debug an Android application. One of the things I need to do is to update the location of the device, and so I have tried to use the Location Controls panel in the Emulator control window. On the Manual tab, I select Decimal, enter a valid latitude and longitude, and then click Send.

Unfortunately, what happens next is that the emulator crashes (logcat output below). Is this a known issue, and if so, is there a workaround? Thanks for any help, Martin

```
02-13 08:54:23.128: INFO/DEBUG(30): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
02-13 08:54:23.128: INFO/DEBUG(30): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:2.3.3/GRI34/101070:eng/test-keys'
02-13 08:54:23.138: INFO/DEBUG(30): pid: 74, tid: 219  >>> system_server <<<
02-13 08:54:23.138: INFO/DEBUG(30): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
02-13 08:54:23.138: INFO/DEBUG(30):  r0 00000000  r1 4081c038  r2 41ae0114  r3 473d9c74
02-13 08:54:23.148: INFO/DEBUG(30):  r4 0000012e  r5 00000000  r6 4081c038  r7 41ae0114
02-13 08:54:23.148: INFO/DEBUG(30):  r8 80701321  r9 80702240  10 00100000  fp 00000001
02-13 08:54:23.158: INFO/DEBUG(30):  ip ae20e7ec  sp 473d9c60  lr ae20acd7  pc ae207dfe  cpsr 00000030
02-13 08:54:23.358: DEBUG/dalvikvm(258): GC_EXPLICIT freed 352K, 56% free 2969K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 126ms
02-13 08:54:23.748: INFO/DEBUG(30):          #00  pc 00007dfe  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so
02-13 08:54:23.748: INFO/DEBUG(30):          #01  pc 0000acd2  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so
02-13 08:54:23.758: INFO/DEBUG(30):          #02  pc 000012ca  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so
02-13 08:54:23.768: INFO/DEBUG(30):          #03  pc 000014ae  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so
02-13 08:54:23.768: INFO/DEBUG(30):          #04  pc 00011a7c  /system/lib/libc.so
02-13 08:54:23.778: INFO/DEBUG(30):          #05  pc 00011640  /system/lib/libc.so
02-13 08:54:23.788: INFO/DEBUG(30): code around pc:
02-13 08:54:23.788: INFO/DEBUG(30): ae207ddc ab04b082 9301cb04 6f646804 b00247a0 
02-13 08:54:23.799: INFO/DEBUG(30): ae207dec bc08bc10 4718b002 b510b40c ab04b082 
02-13 08:54:23.799: INFO/DEBUG(30): ae207dfc 6804cb04 34f89301 47a06824 bc10b002 
02-13 08:54:23.808: INFO/DEBUG(30): ae207e0c b002bc08 46c04718 b510b40c ab04b082 
02-13 08:54:23.818: INFO/DEBUG(30): ae207e1c 9301cb04 34986804 47a06824 bc10b002 
02-13 08:54:23.818: INFO/DEBUG(30): code around lr:
02-13 08:54:23.818: INFO/DEBUG(30): ae20acb4 91099008 f7fb6aa0 900aeab6 1c3a910b 
02-13 08:54:23.830: INFO/DEBUG(30): ae20acc4 6b646b23 930c1c28 1c31940d f7fd9b0f 
02-13 08:54:23.838: INFO/DEBUG(30): ae20acd4 4906f88f 44791c28 f7ff3150 b011fe1d 
02-13 08:54:23.838: INFO/DEBUG(30): ae20ace4 46c0bdf0 000043cc 00004148 00000786 
02-13 08:54:23.848: INFO/DEBUG(30): ae20acf4 f7fbb510 bd10ec24 4802b510 f7fb4478 
02-13 08:54:23.848: INFO/DEBUG(30): stack:
02-13 08:54:23.858: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c20  d97f62b7  
02-13 08:54:23.858: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c24  40c7d685  
02-13 08:54:23.868: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c28  0000000a  
02-13 08:54:23.868: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c2c  00000000  
02-13 08:54:23.878: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c30  0000ab90  [heap]
02-13 08:54:23.878: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c34  80048c1b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-13 08:54:23.888: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c38  0000ab90  [heap]
02-13 08:54:23.888: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c3c  473d9c6c  
02-13 08:54:23.888: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c40  00010004  [heap]
02-13 08:54:23.898: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c44  80037667  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-13 08:54:23.898: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c48  00000000  
02-13 08:54:23.898: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c4c  afd0dcc4  /system/lib/libc.so
02-13 08:54:23.898: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c50  00000000  
02-13 08:54:23.898: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c54  473d9e00  
02-13 08:54:23.898: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c58  df002777  
02-13 08:54:23.908: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c5c  e3a070ad  
02-13 08:54:23.908: INFO/DEBUG(30): #00 473d9c60  00000001  
02-13 08:54:23.908: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c64  ad331275  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
02-13 08:54:23.908: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c68  0000012e  
02-13 08:54:23.918: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c6c  ae20acd7  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so
02-13 08:54:23.918: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c70  41ae0114  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
02-13 08:54:23.918: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c74  00000003  
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30): #01 473d9c78  4284dfce  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c7c  4042b604  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c80  cffeb075  
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c84  c05e8561  
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c88  00000000  
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c8c  00000000  
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c90  00000000  
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c94  00000000  
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c98  00000000  
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9c9c  00000000  
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9ca0  00000000  
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9ca4  00000000  
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9ca8  1e088c00  
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9cac  0000012e  
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9cb0  473d9e56  
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9cb4  00000003  
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9cb8  0000000a  
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9cbc  473d9de8  
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9cc0  00000000  
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9cc4  473d9e6c  
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9cc8  00000001  
02-13 08:54:23.928: INFO/DEBUG(30):     473d9ccc  807012cd  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so
```

Comment: This seems to be the what I'm experiencing as well, might this be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822586/requesting-single-location-update-avd-crashes ? No answers yet.. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [a bug in the 2.3 emulator](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13015) that causes this problem. There is no fix at this time.

Comment: @user309483: ...and there was much rejoicing!

Comment: Recently I downloaded the development environment on a new machine to play around with Android again. But I've run into the same problem.. How was the fix released? Has it been broken again?

Comment: @MartinStam: I just tried the 2.3.3 ARM emulator with the Google APIs and was able to send a location from DDMS over without issue. Google Maps even picked it up.