# Android 2.3.3 GPS freeze

Tags: android, gps, freeze

I am testing with AVD on different API's. On 4.0.3 is working perfectly, but when I test it with 2.3.3 the app crashes and the AVD is restarting each time.

This is my service class:

```
public class SendIntentService extends Service{
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
       MyLocationListener myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener(this);
       Location location = myLocationListener.getLocation();

       double latitude = location.getLatitude();
       double longtitude = location.getLongtitude();

       Log.e("TEST", "lat: " + latitude + " | long: " + longtitude);    

       return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

And this how I get the user location:

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    private Context context;
    private Location location;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private double longtitude = 0.0;
    private double latitude = 0.0;

    public MyLocationListener(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Location getLocation(){

        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean isGpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGpsEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) return null;

        if (isNetworkEnabled){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 
                                                    Constants.MIN_INTERVAL,
                                                    Constants.LOC_DISTANCE,
                                                    this);

            if (locationManager != null){
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (location != null){
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longtitude = location.getLongitude();
                }
            }
        }

        if (isGpsEnabled){
            if (location == null){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                                        Constants.MIN_INTERVAL,
                                                        Constants.LOC_DISTANCE,
                                                        this);

                if (locationManager != null){
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                    if (location != null){
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longtitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return location;
    }

    public double getLatitude(){
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitute(){
        return longtitude;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Permission is set in AndroidManifest. As I said, on 4.0.3 is working perfectly, but on 2.3.3 the app just crashes. I don't know why.

Comment: can you post the stack trace? so we can see the Exception being thrown

Comment: There are no expcetion, the application just freeze out!

Comment: did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985529/android-2-3-emulator-crashes-when-updating-location ?